# ngInclude worked in 1.0.7 but not working in 1.2.1

Tags: angularjs

Working version Angular 1.0.7 [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QUiKuYdOk5hSmeLxZH2k?p=preview)

Not working version Angular 1.2.1 [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/faZ4c1QW4RmKTL19sKxD?p=preview)

In angular 1.0.7, the following ngInclude worked fine:

```
            <li class="dropdown" id="header_notification_bar" data-ng-include="" src="'notifications.tpl.html'" data-ng-controller="NotificationsCtrl"></li>
```

notifications.tp.html looks like this:

```
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
    <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
    <span class="badge">{{notifications.length}}</span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu extended notification">
    <li>
        <p>You have {{notifications.length}} new notifications</p>
    </li>
    <li>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu-list scroller" scroller style="height: 250px">
                <li data-ng-repeat="n in notifications" >
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-plus"></i></span>
                        {{n.summary}}
                    <span class="time">{{n.time}}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="external" >
        <a href="#">See all notifications <i class="m-icon-swapright"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in Angular 1.2.1, the template gets loaded but it seems the view is not bound to the controller/scope.

if you run the 2 plunkrs above and click the exclamation point, you will see that only Angular 1.0.7 shows notification items.

I have read the "Migrating from 1.0 to 1.2" documentation found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) but do not see anything relevant.  Perhaps I am missing something.

Anyone help?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I haven't looked into the underlying cause-- something to do with the scopes created by ngInclude and ngController no longer being shared-- but moving the ng-controller declaration into the wrapping ul seems to be a workaround. [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jfPVZYWwVY5BD7pOcwc?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a change made in passing the controller through to the ng-include.  As @Sarah pointed out, it is probably a scope change.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cw3z8M?p=preview) that is working.

I moved the `ng-controller` into the template itself and it seems to be working again.  But had to wrap the template in a `div` (not ideal, I know).

```
<div data-ng-controller="NotificationsCtrl">
```

I also added the template `src` to the `ng-include` since it is a bit cleaner that way:

```
<li class="dropdown" id="header_notification_bar" data-ng-include="'notifications.tpl.html'"></li>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's the relevant change: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7